# Can I use a function that prints something as an argument for raising an exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that prints some information called `print_info()`. Can I use it to print this info when raising an exception?

```
raise ValueError('This is invalid. Check the valid items here %s' % str(self.print_info()))
```

I can imagine this would be possible in two ways:

1- Call the `print_info()` function to print to stdout instead of providing a string

2- Convert the output of the `print_info()` function to a string and pass it as an argument

I am not sure if this is possible, and if it is, I'm not sure of the correct way to implement it.

Comment: Why not use __repr__() ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its perfectly fine to do it this way as long as the `self.print_info()` returns a string (not printing one!).

An alternative one (which I prefer and will handle the `str` transformation for you) is this:

```
raise ValueError('This is invalid. Check the valid items here {}'.format(self.print_info()))
```

Example 1:

```
class Foo(object):
    def gg(self):
        return 'Hello!'

>>> f = Foo()
>>> raise ValueError('123... {}'.format(f.gg()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 123... Hello!
```

Example 2:

```
class foo(object):
    def gg(self):
        return 'Hello!'
    def xx(self):
        raise ValueError('123... {}'.format(self.gg()))

>>> f = foo()
>>> f.xx()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in xx
ValueError: 123... Hello!
```

Comment: This doesn't work in python2.7. I don't know about later versions though.

Comment: Sure it does. Just tested it. Updated my answer with an example!

Comment: Sure this works, but in my case, I'm not returning a value in gg(). I'm only printing `print 'Hello!'`

Comment: You shouldn't `print`ing. You should return it. Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a statement (in Py2.7) that prints something to standard output. Unless your `print_info` function also *returns* the same string, this won't work.

If you need to use your info string in multiple ways (printing, exceptions, etc.) then it'd be better to have the string creation and the output be separated:

```
def make_info():
    return 'This is my info string.'

def print_info():
    print make_info()

def raise_info():
    raise ValueError('Something happened. See info: {}'.format(make_info())
```

Comment: So the problem is that I already have `make_info()` and `print_info()` which formats the output of `make_info()` in a specific way. I wanted to reuse that format when raising an Exception without having to rewrite the formatting code. The output of `make_info()` is also used in multiple places, so I wanted to avoid formatting there.

Answer (score 0):

A more cleaner approach

```
def print_info():
    print 'This is invalid. Check the valid items here'

try:
    a =  int(raw_input())

except ValueError as p:
    print_info()

else:
    print a
```

*Result*

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
10
10
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
wdfdsnj
This is invalid. Check the valid items here
>>>
```